# Avoid iterators from sets and vectors

Tags: c++, vector, set

I have the following set:

```
        auto comp = [](const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b) -> bool
    { return a.size() < b.size(); };
    auto path = std::set <vector<int>, decltype(comp)> (comp);
```

When I try to get the first element from the set tasks

```
tasks.begin() this will return an iterator of the set
```

Also when I then again try to access the vector of the set:

```
tasks.begin()->begin() this will only return an iterator of the vector.
```

How do I get the first element of the set without any iterator in between?

Comment: `std::set <vector<int> tasks;` - that works for you?

Comment: forgot the last >, edited.

Comment: And how will it be sorted?

Comment: auto comp = [](const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b) -> bool
        { return a.size() < b.size(); };

Comment: Your question raises the question: Why do you need (want) to avoid iterators in the first place? What problem are you trying to solve by this restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The only way to access elements in a `std::set` is through the following methods: begin, end, cbegin, cend, rbegin, rend, crbegin, crend, insert, emplace, emplace_hint, erase, find, equal_range, lower_bound and upper_bound. Every one of them returns either an iterator, a pair of iterators, or a pair with an iterator and a bool.

Comment: And is there a way to assign the first vector in the set (the vector with the least size) to another vector?

Comment: @user2524707: You can erase the smallest vector, and then insert another vector. i.e. `tasks.erase(tasks.begin()); tasks.insert(some_vector);` -- You cannot modify `std::set` elements directly, because doing so might break the set's invariant.

Comment: I want it the other way around. Remove the vector from the set and assign it  to some vector.

Comment: `auto vec = *tasks.begin(); tasks.erase(tasks.begin());`

Comment: why do I have to use auto?

Comment: When did I say you have to use auto? I just used auto to save some typing (savings which has been squandered in having to type this reply).

Comment: I don't, sorry and thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain what you are trying to do, but it is an abuse of the comparator. The following are [requirements on a compare type `T`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare):

> The type `T` satisfies Compare if
>
> - The type `T` satisfies BinaryPredicate, and
>
> Given
>
> - `comp`, an object of type Compare
> - `equiv(a, b)`, an expression equivalent to `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`

If your function does not examine the two and return their order *relative to each other*, it violates this contract and the results will be undefined.

Comment: I want to order the set according to the sizes of the vector.

Comment: His comparison function satisfies the requirements just fine.

Comment: @user2524707 Then what you already have will work fine. The source of confusion is your statement: "How do I get the first element of the set without any iterator in between?" And the answer is you should not be getting that in your comparator.

Comment: I just wanted the smallest element (set.begin) without having to use iterators.

Comment: @user2524707 That already happens given the `set` you've showed us in the example. Trying to: "Assign the first vector in the set (the vector with the least size) to another vector" or "Remove the vector from the set and assign it to some vector." *Must not happen as part of the comparator.*